# groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script5.sai() Possible solutions: wait(), error at line: 3

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am new to `SoapUI and Groovy`. While trying to execute following simple groovy script in SoapUI:

```grovy
log.info "hello"
sai s = new sai(log)
s.name = "baba"
s.pde()
class sai
{
  def log
  def name
  public sai(log)
  {
    this.log=log
  }

  public void pde()
  {
    log.info "sai"+name
  }
}
```

It is giving the following error:

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script5.sai() is applicable for argument types: (sai) values: [sai@1401158] Possible solutions: wait(), wait(long), main([Ljava.lang.String;), run(), run(), any() error at line: 3

Please anybody help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: Your class name should begin with a capital letter

Comment: I ran the code replacing the classname sai by Sai and this works.

Answer (score 0):

As tim_yeates rightly mentioned, it is the standard practise to start the class name with *Captial letters*.

Here is the modified & **groovified** script :

```groovy
log.info 'hello'
//Just pass the data as map as show below
def s = new Sai(log:log, name: 'baba')
s.pde()
class Sai {
  def log
  def name
  //Since we are passing data as map, you do not have to explicity define constructor in the class unless something specific, so removed constructor.
  def pde() { log.info "sai $name" }
}
```

Isn't it so simple?

[image]

*Coming to the issue from your script:*

The way you wrote the script, It appears everything in place, perhaps, it is not able to distinguish, I guess.

In order to make it work:

**Change line from:** 
`sai s = new sai(log)`

**To:** `def s = new sai(log)`
And your script works too with just above change.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It isnt just 'standard practice', it's required by the groovy compiler (unlike java).

Comment: @NathanHughes, thank you, will update. Just a question though. Her code with work with just change mentioned in the answer `def s = new sai(log)`. How it did if that class names has to be Capital mandatory? Would be glad to know.

Comment: @kavitha, did yo get chance to try this?